# Centralizar texto com Card

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

**Preciso alinhar esse titulo e paragrafo junto com a Imagem abaixo, já utilizei, margin-left, padding, display:Inline-block; display: inline-flex; e outros recursos, mais nenhum funcionou.. não quero utilizar o Margin-left: 20px; porque em outras dimensões não ira acompanhar o texto com a imagem..**

[image: Preciso alinhar esse titulo e paragrafo junto com a Imagem abaixo, já utilizei, margin-left, padding, display:Inline-block; display: inline-flex; e outros recursos, mais nenhum funcionou.. não quero utilizar o Margin-left: 20px; porque em outras dimensões não ira acompanhar o texto com a imagem..]

```css
.card{
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  outline-offset: -8px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px ) {
  .card{
    width: 22em;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
  }
}

.card-image{
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: transform .75s;
}

.card:hover .card-image{
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.card-title{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.card-title:hover{
  color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
  transition: .30s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  
  .titulo h2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Rye', cursive;
  }
  
  .titulo p {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <h2>TATTOO</h2>
            <p>Fazemos todos os estilos de tatuagem.</p>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="img5.jpeg" alt="" class="card-image">
                <a href="#" class="card-title">VEJA MAIS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="img4.jpeg" alt="" class="card-image">
                <a href="#" class="card-title">VEJA MAIS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    <div class="container">
        <h2>BODY PIERCERS</h2>
        <p>Tipos de perfurações.</p>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="piercing1.png" alt="" class="card-image">
            <a href="#" class="card-title">VEJA MAIS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="piercing2.jpg" alt="" class="card-image">
            <a href="#" class="card-title">VEJA MAIS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá, você pode fazer de duas formas:
Ou você coloca uma largura automática no teu container (para acompanhar o tamanho dos conteúdos):

```css
.container{
  width:fit-content;
}
```

Ou você centraliza o conteúdo interno do container:

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Veja nos exemplos:
Com fit-content:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Com text-align:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]